# The tab key gives only blanks, how do you go to next EditText with Tab?

Tags: android

i want that when you press the TAB key moves to the next EditText.
At the moment only adds blanks, I'm working on Android 2.3

Anyone know any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i resolved:

```
private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private View view;
    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }


    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.txt_checklocation_location:
            if (txt_checklocation_location.getText().toString().endsWith("\t"))     
            txt_checklocation_location.focusSearch(View.FOCUS_DOWN).requestFocus();
            break;

    }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}


}
```